# Order by count on subquery

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. 1 for venues, 1 for reviews. I am trying to have an sql statement query the tables and order the results depending on the count from the reviews table. It also needs to return venues that have no reviews, but they should be at the end of the result set.

My current SQL statement is:

```
SELECT * , (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS cnt
    FROM ratings r
    WHERE r.venue_id = v.id
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
)
FROM venues AS v
LEFT JOIN ratings AS r ON r.venue_id = v.id
WHERE v.active =  '1'
GROUP BY r.venue_id
LIMIT 20
```

However, this is only returning results that are not in descending count order... Nor is it returning all of the venues, even if they have no rating.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should do something like this. I hope I got it right, I don't have a proper validator.

```
SELECT * 
FROM venues as v LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS cnt, r.venue as ven_id
    FROM ratings r
    GROUP BY ven_id

) as counts
ON v.id = ven_id
WHERE v.active =  '1'
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 20
```

The main difference is that I am selecting also the venue id along with its review count. So we have an ordered count | venue_id list in the inner query. Then you can join the venue id from the venues table to the ven_id from the subquery. I moved the GROUP BY to the subquery.

Comment: @alexsandar - Very close, I did a bit of fiddling to your code and managed to get it to work. Instead of `v.id as ven_id` I put `r.venue_id as ven_id` and it works perfectly

Comment: @MikeF, Absolutely, my mistake! I edited it to be correct. I believe you can edit it yourself if there is something else.

Comment: @Alexsandar - I've just added more ratings to the table and it appears to not be working as intended. There are currently 3 results from a count query on the ratings table. 5,4,1. However, it's returning it in 4,5,1 result on the query.

Comment: I see... It seems like you need another order by on the outside query, instead of the subquery, since the order gets mixed up after the join (which is by SQL definition not to keep any implicit ordering, to be honest). That means moving the ORDER BY on the outside. That gets close what @axiac wrote.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` in the sub-query is completely useless (and I think MySQL will just ignore it). It needs to be moved to the outer query to have effect. The same remark/solution for the query posted in the question.

Comment: @MikeF sub-queries are usually slow because they need to be executed again and again for each row of the outer query. If you are lucky, MySQL will internally morph the query into another one that doesn't contain sub-queries. I think the query presented in this answer can be changed this way (MySQL will produce something equivalent with the one I posted in my answer) but I'm not sure if it can fix the query from the question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the request correctly, this query should produce the result you expect:

```
SELECT v.*, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM venues AS v
LEFT JOIN ratings AS r ON r.venue_id = v.id
WHERE v.active =  '1'
GROUP BY r.venue_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```